# What does the pipeline for core animation look like?

Tags: ios, core-animation

I've invested in custom animation frameworks for my app but am running into minor but annoying frame drops.

I've been very careful to keep the main thread clear but it seems iOS occasionally pre-empts my app for longer than 33ms (30fps) presumably because the scheduler is dropping my interactive status b/c of heavy animation calculations.  (These frameworks are calculating and updating vertexes themselves)

If I reworked these animation frameworks to rely on core animation by approximating the results with chunks of CA tweening, will this free my app from having to be scheduled runnable during animation commits?  I read somewhere that QuartzServer runs on an independent processs, but I don't know how CA is divided among the daemon during actual animation tweening.